# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/wsdl/OperationType

Tags: soap

Feb 11, 2016 1:43:17 PM org.apache.axis.utils.JavaUtils isAttachmentSupported
WARNING: Unable to find required classes (javax.activation.DataHandler and javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart). Attachment support is disabled.
Feb 11, 2016 1:43:17 PM org.springframework.scheduling.support.TaskUtils$LoggingErrorHandler handleError
SEVERE: Unexpected error occurred in scheduled task.
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/wsdl/OperationType
    at org.apache.axis.description.OperationDesc.(OperationDesc.java:59)
    at in.gov.sadmapi.tempuri.Dept_AuthenticationSoapStub._initOperationDesc1(Dept_AuthenticationSoapStub.java:26)
    at in.gov.sadmapi.tempuri.Dept_AuthenticationSoapStub.(Dept_AuthenticationSoapStub.java:20)
    at in.gov.sadmapi.tempuri.Dept_AuthenticationLocator.getDept_AuthenticationSoap(Dept_AuthenticationLocator.java:55)
    at in.gov.sadmapi.tempuri.Dept_AuthenticationLocator.getDept_AuthenticationSoap(Dept_AuthenticationLocator.java:50)
    at in.gov.sadmapi.tempuri.Dept_AuthenticationSoapProxy._initDept_AuthenticationSoapProxy(Dept_AuthenticationSoapProxy.java:18)
    at in.gov.sadmapi.tempuri.Dept_AuthenticationSoapProxy.(Dept_AuthenticationSoapProxy.java:8)
    at in.gov.sadmapi.service.TransactionSyncServiceImpl.processSyncService(TransactionSyncServiceImpl.java:89)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy27.processSyncService(Unknown Source)
    at in.gov.sadmapi.service.SyncScheduler.processSync(SyncScheduler.java:19)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.ScheduledMethodRunnable.run(ScheduledMethodRunnable.java:65)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.wsdl.OperationType
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1714)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)
    ... 35 more

Comment: So, as there is no question, what would you expect us to do?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The specified classes are missing from the project classpath at the time of execution.
Add the following dependency to your pom :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>wsdl4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>wsdl4j</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks Chandu, it's works.

Comment: `<version>1.6.3</version>` is not working !

Comment: @AlirezaFattahi I cannot confirm. At least it works on my machine, using java11 plus mentioned 1.6.3.